# Why ReactNative cli app icon is not changed on the emulator after updating res files correctly

Tags: android, react-native, mobile-application, react-native-cli, appicon

[i updated correctly the res files but no result on emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs9ZE.png)

I try to change the app icon i generated app icon 5 files then i replaced the files to res but after building restarting emulator my app icon is not changed in react-native cli not expo

Comment: Have you uninstalled the older version of your app yet?

Comment: what do you mean apk file on the emulator?

Comment: Yes. Uninstall your app and reinstall it

Comment: yes i did not chnanged

Comment: Make sure you updated for the all different densities and variations.